# Trying to copy conditional format to pivottable

Tags: vba, excel

All I really want to do is copy the conditional format from each column in a source range to the corresponding columns on a pivottable. It's getting closer, but now I'm getting an error 1004 while trying to apply the format. Here's the code:

```
    Sub CreatePivot()
        ' Define RngTarget and RngSource as Range type variables
        Dim RngTarget As Range
        Dim RngSource As Range
        Dim intLastCol As Integer
        Dim intCntrCol As Integer
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim pt As PivotTable

        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        ws.Cells.Clear

        ' RngTarget is where the PivotTable will be created (ie: Sheet2, Cell B3)
        Set RngTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B3")

        ' RngSource defines the Range that will be used to create the PivotTable
        Set RngSource = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

        ' Select the Range
        RngSource.Select

        ' Copy the Range into the clipboard
        RngSource.Copy

        ' Create a new PivotTable using the RngSource defined above
        ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, RngSource).CreatePivotTable RngTarget, "PivotB3"
        Set pt = RngTarget.PivotTable

        ' Get the last used column from the data table
        intLastCol = RngSource.Columns(RngSource.Columns.Count).Column

        ' Select the Pivot table so we can apply the conditional formats
        pt.PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True

        ' ERROR! Error when "ws.Range(Cells(5, intCtrCol)).Select" is first called
        For intCntrCol = 3 To intLastCol
            ws.Range(Cells(5, intCtrCol)).Select ' Select the current Sum column
            Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLess, Formula1:="=5000" ' Set conditional format to less than 5000
            Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority ' Take priority over any other formats
            With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font ' Use the Font property for the next operations
                .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1 ' Set it to the default (if it does not meet the condition)
                .TintAndShade = 0 ' Same as above
            End With
            With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 65535 ' Set the background color to Yellow
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
            Selection.FormatConditions(1).ScopeType = xlFieldsScope ' Apply the format to all rows that match "Sum of xxxx"
        Next intCntrCol
    End Sub
```

Comment: with runtime errors its good to debug step by step

Comment: Oh boy ... yeah .. now I see it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is the exact same issue as in your last question, as you suspected, but there is a little more that needs to be fixed as well. If you are going to be doing any significant Excel VBA development going forward, you should definitely spend the time to learn the patterns you can use to avoid `.Select`.

Alternatively, you can simply select the pivot table sheet before modifying it. Note that **this is NOT a best practice**, but will allow your code to run.

Add this row immediately above your ' ERROR! comment:

```
ws.Select
```

You misspelled the variable name in the first row in your for loop. The counter is called `intCntrCol` and you refer to it as `intCtrCol`. Get in the habit of compiling your code as you work and you'll never have these kinds of errors. **Debug -> Compile**

You can't select a range with the syntax you are using. Instead of

```
ws.Range(Cells(5, intCtrCol)).Select
```

you need

```
ws.Cells(5, intCntrCol).Select
```

Comment: `ws.Activate`? or am i wrong?

Comment: ws.select will generate an error. =) ws.activate, then just do the Cells(blah).Select without ws.range() jazz around it and it should work. And yes Select can be very finniky and any sort of long term usage macro should strive to avoid it - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221576(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: ws.activate will also generate an error. There is more wrong with the code than just the activesheet. I'm modifying my answer now.

Comment: Ok. I've got those changes done. I did catch a few of them on my own, luckily. And now everything is working except for the second to last line in the sub. I will spend the time to work out avoiding selects. I normally always call full parent.child paths in other programming, but this one I'm still new to and unfortunately am in a bit of a time crunch so I just have to get it done and working.

Comment: Good to hear. Good luck with your deadline.